Why image upload is not working for Django when using docker
I have an ImageField in my Django blog application that uploads images to a specific folder. The setup works perfectly when I run the application using python manage.py runserver; the image is uploaded to the intended folder without any issues.
However, when I run the application in Docker using docker-compose, the image is not being uploaded. The Docker logs (docker logs <container-name>) do not show any errors.
Here’s the relevant part of my setup:
I use /Works/app-media as the target folder for uploaded images. I also tested this folder is mounted properly. I verified this by creating a file inside the container at /app/media, and it correctly reflects in the local folder.
Here’s my docker-compose.yml configuration for reference:
services:
  admin-backend-service:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: admin-backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./static:/app/static
      - /Works/app-media:/app/media
    environment:
      DEBUG: "0"
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: "admin.dypzen.com"
    restart: always

I use .env file to load the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT to my settings.py and I have tested if these variables are loading properly
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getenv('MEDIA_ROOT', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = os.getenv('MEDIA_URL', '/media/')

For clarity I'm sharing a part of my models.py file to see how I defined the ImageField for my blog post app
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='blog_videos', blank=True, null=True)

Edit
I have removed the DEBUG:0 from the docker-compose.yml file and this issue is persistent in local development environment also

you set DEBUG = False, Django does not serve media files in production.

how do you set the DEBUG variable in settings? What HTTP response do you get when you manually request the media file in a browser?

@willeM_VanOnsem in settings the DEBUG value is TRUE. I'm getting 404 error when trying the image manually in the network tab. I think it is because the url.py setting is not configured to access the uploaded image. I assume even if we fix this we will get 'Not found' error since the the image file is not uploaded

how dou set the DEBUG in settings? How do you parse the environment variable?

Django does not serve media/static files in production [Django-doc] (with DEBUG = False). Indeed, Django's way to serve static/media files when you develop (DEBUG = True) is inefficient and likely contains security vulnerabilities.
Typically you serve such files by a webserver like nginx or Apache, or you use a cloud service like an Amazon S3 bucket. This allows efficient caching, streaming larger media files, and making content globally accessible through a content delivery network (CDN).
You thus will have to set up an webserver like nginx in your docker that serves static and media files, and forwards requests to the Django backend. Typically this webserver is also used to implement HTTPS such that Django servers the underlying HTTP requests. You can find details how to configure the webserver in the Django documentation [Django-doc].

Thanks for the direction and I will update after trying to serve the file using Apache.
